# Increase voltage of a 1.6MHz frequency

Tags: pwm, signal, piezo, piezoelectricity

I have a digital signal with voltage of 3V and frequency of 1.6MHz. How can I increase voltage of this signal to 36V? The signal is generated by PWM feature of esp32.

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to use this signal to feed a piezoelectrical layer which is used to generate cold vapor. That thing consumes 0.5 ampere on 36V which is something about 18 watts.
The DC Source is totally customizable but at this stage it is a simple AC to DC adapter.

Comment: Need much more info to answer this question.

Comment: If it is just PWM, the easiest might be to switch a mosfet that has a low enough gate capacitance. But it also depends on the load capacitance, impedance, inductance... please add some more info to your question.

Comment: I've added some more info to my question by the way, what else can I add ? @SimSon

Comment: What is your load for the 12V signal? And "A DC source"? What is it?

Comment: The things I mentioned are essential to select a suitable MOSFET: load capacity, distance/wiring to the load (aka inductance). How much power are we talking about? Driving piezo transducers is not trivial if they require a frequency that high.

Comment: There are ultrasonic mist makers on the market for just a few bucks. Don't they work for your purpose?

Comment: @SimSon Does that MOSFET circuit need any special efforts ? And no because we need to play with frequency which effects on size of water drops which matters.

Comment: I have also added some information about loads

Comment: At 1.6Mhz, you will need a fast gate driver for the mosfet, the ESP32 gpio outputs can't source/sink anywhere near the required power to switch the gate on a power mosfet at this rate.  Also, piezo drivers for misters have a relatively high Q, they resonate at a particular frequency and the drivers are designed to seek this resonate frequency at their output.  If you are planning on varying the frequency by anything more than 1 or 2% you will get very low acoustic output at the transducer.

Comment: Yes, the MOSFET circuit requires special efforts. You need to actively drive the output high *and low* to allow fast discharge of load capacitance. You even need to drive the gate capacitance itself - (dis-)charging a capacity with high frequency results in high current. A fast H-bridge would be ideal, so you can effectively double the amplitude (control polarity with PWM). Those are the main points to be concerned about, IMO.